# ADFS not issuing claims from custom attribute stores to some users

Tags: active-directory, claims-based-identity, adfs, adfs2.0

I'm trying to work out why some of our users aren't issued claims by our custom attribute stores.

Our main attribute store for authentication is Active Directory, but we are using two custom attribute stores to issue several custom claims to users, and also to perform some logging of claims issued. When an affected user logs in, they are authenticated successfully by AD, but have no more claims added. According to the logging in our attribute stores, the BeginExecuteQuery is never called.

I can't see anything to link the affected users, but they mainly seem to be new users, or users that have not logged into the system in a long time. Restarting ADFS sometimes clears the problem, but whether it does or not seems to be random.

I'm trying to understand why an attribute store would be ignored by ADFS on logon for certain users, when it works fine for others. If there is a quick guaranteed temporary fix to get users' claims issued correctly, that would be useful too!

For security reasons, I don't have access to the ADFS Debug tracing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was eventually solved with a longs string of calls to Microsoft's AD FS support team. The problem was traced to a piece of our claims rule language which was using the `lastLogon` and `lastLogonTimestamp` AD attributes without understanding how they actually behaved. This meant that for some users the condition to grant the custom claims was never met.